# Basic Thread Locking in C#.NET WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, thread-safety

This seems like a basic question, but Google has not helped me... How do I do basic thread locking in C#.NET WPF? In my fairly simple user application, I have multiple threads performing time-intensive operations that save their results into one common data structure or read from this common data structure. I'd like to be able to lock() and unlock() around access to this data structure to maintain thread safety. However, there are many different places in my code that I access this data structure from, not just one. What .NET objects are used to implement this locking?

Comment: I find it difficult to believe you can't find something about thread syncrhonisation in C# using Google, or even the SO search... search for 'lock', 'manualresetevent', 'monitor', 'interlocked'...

Comment: The lock statement is a good place to start your research, and is the default answer unless you need more complex semantics: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx

Comment: Try using `http://searchdotnet.com` to do you .NET searches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
public static class LockHolder
{
    public static object Lock = new object();
}
```

then, in your code, use:

```
lock(LockHolder.Lock)
{
    //your safe code
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz(v=vs.71).aspx

I guess a little more info may be helpful. IIRC, the `lock(object o)` is basicly a macro that will be expanded by the compiler and then restrict access to your *safe code*, which is what you'd expect. What isn't necessarily obvious is that **any** object `o` can be a lock, and each `o` is needed for each safe lock. if I have

```
object a = new object();
object b = new object();
```

and perform a `lock(a)` then that **will not** prevent access to something with a `lock(b)` around it. Most code samples show a `lock(this)` which will lock to the *current instance* of the particular class, which is not what you want if you need a global lock and have multiple instances of that class running around.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to get synchronization achieved. Please see the screenshot which I have created
[image]

Comment: although this is nice it doesn't really answer the question - which one should be used in which circumstance?

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to  use [thread safe data structures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305.aspx) such as those found in the [System.Collections.Concurrent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx) namespace. They do all the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check this brilliant article on CodeProject by Sacha Barber.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27366/Beginner-s-Guide-to-Threading-in-NET-Part-3-of-n

It explains few synchronization mechanisms..

Cheers