# GUI refresh in a multithread application causes exception

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, exception, user-interface

In my file searching application I have a problem with refreshing the GUI `(OnPropertyChanged)`

I begin with all my checked dirs:

```
foreach (string folderPath in dirList) {   
    this.Search (fileSearchPattern, folderPath);
}
```

In this method I start a background worker...

```
public void Search(string fileSearchPattern, string folderPath)
{
    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.DoWork += BackgroundSearch;
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(BackgroundSearchCompleted);
    bw.RunWorkerAsync(new string[] { fileSearchPattern, folderPath });
}
```

...and I get the file list for current folder path:

```
private void BackgroundSearch(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    e.Result = new HashSet<string>(
        GetFileList(
            (e.Argument as string[])[0],
            (e.Argument as string[])[1]));
}
```

When I have the file list, I fire an event to add the items to my result DataTable:

```
void BackgroundSearchCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.ItemsAdded != null)
    {
        // fire event files found:
        this.ItemsAdded(e.Result as HashSet<string>);
    }
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is the event handler of the event ItemsAdded.
Here I start a background worker again to get file info for all files:

```
public void AddItems(HashSet<string> fileNames)
{
    if (fileNames.Count > 0)
    {
        lock (this.searchResult)
        {
            this.searchResult.BeginLoadData();
            foreach (string n in fileNames)
            {
                this.searchResult.Rows.Add(
                    new object[] {null, null, null, null, null, null, 
                        n // Filename
                });
            }
            this.searchResult.EndLoadData();
        }

        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.DoWork += BackgroundFileInfo;
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(BackgroundSearchCompleted);
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}

private void BackgroundFileInfo(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    lock (this.searchResult)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in this.searchResult.Rows)
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(row["FULL_NAME"].ToString());
            row.BeginEdit();
            row["FILE_NAME"] = fi.Name;
            row["DIRECTORY_NAME"] = fi.DirectoryName;
            row["ATTRIB"] = fi.Attributes;
            row["CREATION"] = fi.CreationTime.ToShortDateString() + " " +
                fi.CreationTime.ToShortTimeString();
            row["LAST_WRITE"] = fi.LastWriteTime.ToShortDateString() + " " +
                fi.LastWriteTime.ToShortTimeString();
            row["LAST_ACCESS"] = fi.LastAccessTime.ToShortDateString() + " " +
                fi.LastAccessTime.ToShortTimeString();
            row.EndEdit();
        }
        this.searchResult.AcceptChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

When getting my file informations is done, I want to refresh my GUI,
but here I get an Exception "An instance is null" (or something like that )

```
void BackgroundFileInfoCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    lock (this.searchResult)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("SearchResult"); // <<== HERE I HAVE AN EXCEPTION!!!
    }
}
```

What could be the reason behind this error?

Comment: You should really use a separate object for holding the lock.  Just create an `Object lock` and lock on that, not on your `searchResult` variable.

Comment: The exception has a type and a stack-trace. Please add them exactly to your qeustion. Without them we can't guess anything. The problem is not it the code you have posted.

Comment: Also can you just post the entire error, it's unclear what is wrong from what you posted.

Comment: Here you can find more informations about the error:

http://s14.directupload.net/file/d/3180/y3gd3vyh_png.htm
http://s1.directupload.net/file/d/3180/5nl2pcnv_png.htm

Stacktrace is too long, but this is a short version:

Comment: ItemContainerGenerator.Remove * 
ItemContainerGenerator.System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.IRecyclingItemContainerGenerator.Recycle * 
VirtualizingStackPanel.CleanupRange * 
VirtualizingStackPanel.CleanupContainers * 
VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverride * 
Controls.Primitives.DataGridRowsPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint) * 
FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize) * 
UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize) * 
ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()

Comment: I have implemented these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522833/basic-thread-locking-in-c-net-wpf lock solution, but the error isn't going away

Answer (score 0):

This may be because of OnPropertyChanged("SearchResult") trying to update the data bound control which is owned by some dispather.

try with `Dispather.CurrentDispather.BeginInvoke`

Comment: I have implemented Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate { OnPropertyChanged("SearchResult"); }); But the error isn't going away